# KDE plasma desktop: pointer cursor required during presentation

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, mouse-pointer, effects, presentation

I use my Kubuntu 22.04 system for teaching, often (but not always) with okular.

What I would like to have, especially in presentations with okular running in full-screen mode, is a cursor that becomes visible when it is moved, a bit like a laser pointer.

What I have found are desktop effects for "track mouse" (under accessibility), but these are not what I need. These create rotating semi-circles that are always visible and rather intrusive.

I have considered using another pdf viewer, but okular works well with embedded movies that I sometimes have in my slide. The other pdf viewers I tried did not display these properly.

Comment: In okular settings, you can choose the cursor to be always hidden, always visible or hidden after delay for presentation mode. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: not quite, I am looking for a cursor that looks more like a pointer or leaves a well-visible trail.

Comment: the okular cursor is almosts invisible to me. It is the shape of an I beam and very skinny. that is the general ubuntu shape when hovering over text. not a pointer. however I got better results in okular settings accessibility , convert to black and white.